# Exclude a single test file from Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, include

I have two test files in the **same** package. I would like gradle to run foo/ATest but not foo/BTest. Is there a way to set this up? At the moment I can't seem to exclude BTest when I include ATest. That is, this doesn't work:

```
test {
    java {
        srcDirs 'testSrc'
        include '**/foo/ATest.java'
        exclude '**/foo/BTest.java'
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear and easy documentation here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Test Filter [TestFilter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html) to do it:

```
test {
  java {
      srcDirs 'testSrc'
  }
  filter {
    includeTestsMatching "*.foo.ATest"
  }
}
```